# Cannot add property, object is not extensible when binding props in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

For some reason when I try to bind a function to a prop in my React component, it is coming up with

> TypeError: Can't add property onSearch, object is not extensible.

I am not too familiar with what this means or why it is appearing, I think it may be to do with the es6 bindings which I am still finding my way around on.

Here are the two most relevant components.

**Searchbox**

```
import React from 'react';

import SearchForm from 'SearchForm';
import searchDisplay from 'searchDisplay';
import googleRequests from 'googleRequests';

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        searchResults: []
    }
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);


}
handleSearch(searchTerm) {
    googleRequests.search(searchTerm).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.items);
        this.extrapolateResults(response.items);
    }), ((error) =>{
        console.log(error)
    });
}
//pull relevant data out of api call
extrapolateResults(arr) {
    function Book(objInArr) {
        this.link = objInArr.selfLink;
        this.bookTitle = objInArr.volumeInfo.title;
        this.author = objInArr.volumeInfo.authors;
        this.bookDescription = objInArr.volumeInfo.description;
        this.thumbnail = function() {
            if (objInArr.volumeInfo.hasOwnProperty('imageLinks')){
            return objInArr.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail
        } 
        else {
            return "No Thumbnail Available";
        }
    };
        this.thumbnailPic = this.thumbnail();
}
//push extrapolated data into array
var finalRes = [];
var initRes = arr;
    initRes.forEach(function (objInArr) {
        var obj = new Book(objInArr);
        finalRes.push(obj);
    })
this.setState({
    searchResults: finalRes
})
console.log(finalRes, this.state.searchResults)

}


render() {
    var res = this.state.searchResults;

    function renderResults() {
        if (res.length !== 0) {
            return (<SearchDisplay content={res} />)
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }

    var style = {
        border: '1px solid black',
        height: '80%',
        width: '83%'
    }
    return (
        <div style={style}>
            <SearchForm onSearch={this.handleSearch}> </SearchForm>
        </div>)
}
};

export default SearchBox;
```

**Searchform**

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.props.onSearch = props;
}
onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var searchTerm = this.refs.searchTerm.value;
    if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
        this.refs.searchTerm.value = '';
        this.props.onSearch(searchTerm);
    }
}

render() {
    var style = {
        border: '1px solid black',
        float: 'left',
        height: '100%',
        width: '30%'
    }

    return(
        <div style={style} className="container">
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="search name here" ref="searchTerm"/>
                <input type="submit" className="button" value="Get Book"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        );
}
};

export default SearchForm;
```

I have a feeling I am missing something very simple but after googling this issue for a while I still can't figure out what it is...

Answer (score 3):

remove `this.props.onSearch = props;`... not sure what you wanted to do there on that line

Comment: Thank you, it has resolved this issue but I am now getting TypeError 'this.props.onSearch is not a function' in the console. 

I think there may be a bigger issue but I can't figure out where.

Comment: are you using `<SearchForm>` component in any other place where onSearch is not defined...? it is defined in the code you posted... in the console it should tell you maybe more info about where the error is happening

anyway you can change the onSearch call line to `this.props.onSearch && this.props.onSearch(searchTerm);` so it calls it only if it is defined

Answer (score 0):

change handleSearch function definition to handleSearch = () => {} fat arrow function
it will work fine in searchbox file.